# What is good implementation on updating items that shift around a lot in RecyclerView (swapping), and immediate user feedback?

Tags: android, synchronization, adapter, android-recyclerview

## **Goal(s)**:

- 1: Effortless updating for dynamic items.

  - Example:

    - I have a `List<T>` returned from an API, I use that list in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`. User swipes to refresh and a new list is returned from the API containing *some* new items and *some* updated old items. Now the older list needs to remove duplicate items.
  - Note: assume all items have an `updated` attribute that might change if a user interacts with it.
- 2: Immediate user feedback (this might tie in with goal #1).

  - Example:

    - To insert a new item into the `RecyclerView.Adapter` it needs to be created in an API first. Implementation creates object in the `RecyclerView.Adapter` and in the API simultaneously. When the new object is returned from the API the immediate object that was previously injected right away into the `RecyclerView.Adapter` "syncs" with the API response. This way the user sees immediate feedback.

---

## **Code Example:**

I don't really have anything in mind for Goal #1 BUT for Goal 2 I was thinking something like this maybe inside my `ViewHolder`? (I have heard that updating / syncing models in Viewholders is not a good practice in general because viewholders recycle):

```
// JAVA 7
private void createNewObjectToBeInsertedIntoRecyclerView(String data) {

    // Pass callback to API and at the same time insert object into adapter
    mAdapter.addNewObject(data);
    mPresenter.createObject(new SyncRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessFromAPI(ModelObject model) {
            mAdapter.updateObject(model);
        }
    });
}

// JAVA 8
private void createNewObjectToBeInsertedIntoRecyclerView(String data) {

    // Pass callback to API and at the same time insert object into adapter
    mAdapter.addNewObject(data);
    mPresenter.createObject((sync) -> { mAdapter.updateObject(model); });
}
```

This is just off the top of my head and it is definitely bug prone.

## **How Can I Achieve This?**:

Looking for a robust solution here, but something that doesn't involve content providers (if possible).

Comment: Exactly how large a list are you expecting? Planning to display a thousand items vs a dozen or so can affect the possible solutions.  Can you expand on #2? It sounds like you want to replicate data in two different places...which I'm not sure how that gives `immediate user feedback`.  Finally how often do you expect your data to be updating?  Few times a second or simply from user interaction?

Comment: The list can vary depending on how long the user has scrolled down, so if the user is on the app for an average of say 15 mins you can expect more than 200 items or so. How often does the data need to be updated? I would hinder on when the user scrolls down to refresh or swipes to refresh is when the updating should happen imo. Otherwise i see problems for battery life. Assume each item has an ID and a creation date, there are no duplicate lists just one, currently the way I do it is via O^2 runtime, looping through the list and removing / re-adding the updated item. Hoping for a better ans.

Comment: If you're still not clear I can update the question to give you a better idea of the problem I'm dealing with.

Comment: I got enough for writing an answer on #1.  Still not understanding #2 very well though.

Answer (score -1):

You should not do anything like that in the `ViewHolder`, just bind the data you got from the API to the UI.

What you should do is operate on the `Adapter`

1. when the new `List<T>` returns from the API, just make the old list in the adapter to point to this new one (`oldList = newList`) and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
2. You can do like point 1) but that way updates the whole `Adapter`. If you know where in the `Adapter` you have inserted that item (and I assume you know), just call `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position)` or alternatively,  if you have already created it the `Adapter`, call `mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: This does not answer the question and is very basic in its implementation. For example "just point the list to the new list" would delete all the other items in my list. What if I had 100 items and the new list only returned 5 items?

Comment: Just update the items that have changed then. Do you need the code?

Comment: This problem is more complicated than you are implicating, I have multiple types of viewholders that need to be synced with data from an API, as well as simulate immediate user feedback. I have a semi solution to this which ill be posting up. And you're solution is a bare bones one, something I figured out on my first attempt at tackling this problem.

Comment: Then you explained the problem very poorly. Wait for you semisolution. Anyway multiple view types should not affect the syncing as they're just a way to display the data!